# how to solve “instantiate chaincode” error in fabric-sdk-java?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I use fabrc-sdk-java to operate the e2e_cli network.The e2e uses CA and the TLS is disabled.

I successfully create the channel and install the chaincode.

create channel：

```
Channel newChannel = client.newChannel(myChannel.getChannelName(), orderer, channelConfiguration, channelConfigurationSignatures.toArray(new byte[myPeerOrgs.size()][]));
```

`channelConfigurationSignatures` contains signatures from two organizations.

install chaincode:

Every organization has to send an installation proposal once, using its own `peerAdmin` organization.

reference：https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk

But,when I prepare to instantiate chaincode,I get the error:

```
0endorser failed with Sending proposal to peer0.org1.example.com failed because of: gRPC failure=Status{code=UNKNOWN, description=Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1 is unknown, cause=null}. Was verified:false
```

These are related codes：

```
 client.setUserContext(myPeerOrgs.get(0).getPeerAdmin());

        InstantiateProposalRequest instantiateProposalRequest = client.newInstantiationProposalRequest();
    instantiateProposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(fabricConfig.getProposalWaitTime());
        instantiateProposalRequest.setChaincodeID(chaincodeID);

        instantiateProposalRequest.setFcn(ininFun);
        instantiateProposalRequest.setArgs(args);

        Map<String, byte[]> tm = new HashMap<>();
        tm.put("HyperLedgerFabric", "InstantiateProposalRequest:JavaSDK".getBytes(UTF_8));
        tm.put("method", "InstantiateProposalRequest".getBytes(UTF_8));
        instantiateProposalRequest.setTransientMap(tm);

        ChaincodeEndorsementPolicy chaincodeEndorsementPolicy = new ChaincodeEndorsementPolicy();
        chaincodeEndorsementPolicy.fromYamlFile(new File(myChaincode.getChaincodeEndorsementPolicyPath()));
        instantiateProposalRequest.setChaincodeEndorsementPolicy(chaincodeEndorsementPolicy);

        logger.trace("Sending instantiateProposalRequest to all peers with arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args));

        Collection<ProposalResponse> successful = new LinkedList<>();
        Collection<ProposalResponse> failed = new LinkedList<>();

        Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = channel.sendInstantiationProposal(instantiateProposalRequest);

        for (ProposalResponse response : responses) {
            if (response.isVerified() && response.getStatus() == ProposalResponse.Status.SUCCESS) {
                successful.add(response);
                logger.trace(String.format("Succesful instantiate proposal response Txid: %s from peer %s", response.getTransactionID(), response.getPeer().getName()));
            } else {
                failed.add(response);
            }
        }
        logger.trace(String.format("Received %d instantiate proposal responses. Successful+verified: %d . Failed: %d", responses.size(), successful.size(), failed.size()));
        if (failed.size() > 0) {
            ProposalResponse first = failed.iterator().next();
            logger.error("Not enough endorsers for instantiate :" + successful.size() + "endorser failed with " + first.getMessage() + ". Was verified:" + first.isVerified());
            System.exit(1);
        }
```

I thought it was a serialization problem，but the MyUser class and the MyEnrollement class both inherit the Serializable interface, and both define the serialVersionUID.

I have compared `blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk` and have not identified the problem.

Comment: Oh,the version of fabric-sdk-java is 1.0.0,the fabric network version is also 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem.The problem is in the following code:

```
Channel newChannel = client.newChannel(myChannel.getChannelName(), orderer, channelConfiguration, channelConfigurationSignatures.toArray(new byte[myPeerOrgs.size()][]));
```

The above code is written by me with reference to `End2endIT`:

```
//Create channel that has only one signer that is this orgs peer admin. If channel creation policy needed more signature they would need to be added too.
Channel newChannel = client.newChannel(name, anOrderer, channelConfiguration, client.getChannelConfigurationSignature(channelConfiguration, sampleOrg.getPeerAdmin()));
```

I don't know if it is wrong with my usage.But my code, the error is in this sentence, when joining the node later, the error is reported.

I referenced https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk/blob/master/java/src/main/java/org/app/network/CreateChannel.java and found the correct way of writing.

```
public Channel createChannel() {

        logger.info("Begin  create channel: " + myChannel.getChannelName());

        ChannelConfiguration channelConfiguration = new ChannelConfiguration(new File(fabricConfig.getChannelArtifactsPath() + "/" + myChannel.getChannelName() + ".tx"));
        logger.trace("Read channel " + myChannel.getChannelName() + " configuration file：" + fabricConfig.getChannelArtifactsPath() + "/" + myChannel.getChannelName() + ".tx");
        byte[] channelConfigurationSignatures = client.getChannelConfigurationSignature(channelConfiguration, myPeerOrgs.get(0).getPeerAdmin());

        Channel newChannel = client.newChannel(myChannel.getChannelName(), orderer, channelConfiguration, channelConfigurationSignatures);;

        for (Peer peer : myPeerOrgs.get(0).getPeers()) {
            // create a channel for the first time, only `joinPeer` here, not `addPeer`
            newChannel.joinPeer(peer);
        }
        for (EventHub eventHub : myPeerOrgs.get(0).getEventHubs()) {
            newChannel.addEventHub(eventHub);
        }

        if (!newChannel.isInitialized()) {
            newChannel.initialize();
        }

        // I have only tested two organizations
        // I don’t know if there are any errors in the three organizations.
        for (int i = 1; i < myPeerOrgs.size(); i++) {
            client.setUserContext(myPeerOrgs.get(i).getPeerAdmin());
            newChannel = client.getChannel(myChannel.getChannelName());
            for (Peer peer : myPeerOrgs.get(i).getPeers()) {
                newChannel.joinPeer(peer);
            }
            for (EventHub eventHub : myPeerOrgs.get(i).getEventHubs()) {
                newChannel.addEventHub(eventHub);
            }
        }

        logger.trace("Node that has joined the channel：");
        Collection<Peer> peers = newChannel.getPeers();
        for (Peer peer : peers) {
            logger.trace(peer.getName() + " at " + peer.getUrl());
        }

        logger.info("Success, end create channel: " + myChannel.getChannelName() + "\n");

        return newChannel;
    }
```

Related code later, such as installing and initializing chaincode, also refer to https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk. This is an excellent example.

If anyone knows how to use the fourth variable parameter of `newChannel`, please let me know. Thanks.

Finally, I don't know how to dynamically join nodes, organizations and channels, I am looking for and testing, there are only examples of nodejs on the network, there is no java, if anyone knows, please tell me, I really need. Thanks.